# mutually exclusive checkboxes in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a following problem:
I have two attributes that are both boolean but should also be mutually exclusive. Because they are two different attributes I can't implement them as radio buttons but must resort to check_boxes.

How can I make certain it is not possible to check both as true?
This is a nested form - so it is probable that there would be more than one set of this attributes (as there could possibly be more than one object).

```
<table>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <%= f.label :prerequisite, "Check if prerequisite:" %>
     <%= f.check_box :prerequisite %> 
    </td>
    <td>
     <%= f.label :punishment, "Check if punishment:" %>
     <%= f.check_box :punishment %> 
    </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

EDIT:

When I add this script to the file it works fine for the first occurance of the table of the form, not for the others:

```
  <script>$("tr").on("change", ":checkbox", function(){
   if( $(this).is(":checked") ) {
       $(this).parent().parent().find(":checkbox").not($(this)).attr('checked', false);
   }});</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a third radio for `neither`

```html
<input type="radio" name="lorem" value="prerequisite">prerequisite<br>
<input type="radio" name="lorem" value="punishment">punishment<br>
<input type="radio" name="lorem" value="neither">neither
```

Comment: This would work for "select a, b or c" form one attribute. But these are two different attributes that both have true or false.

Comment: Just change the data to use two attributes on the server-side. Don't make it complicated on the client. Or, add validation so that if they check one while the other is checked, then show a form error.